# MQ MQHMDE throwing MQRC_HEADER_ERROR

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm working one mq based application where i need to set JMS_IBM_Format as MQHMDE header, whenever i try to use this header i'm getting ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2142' ('MQRC_HEADER_ERROR') error. Could you please help me how to place a message when using MQHMDE header

these are the info i'm using while sending

```
JMSDeliveryMode - Persistent
JMS_IBM_Format - MQConstants.MQFMT_MD_EXTENSION
JMS_IBM_Character_Set - 785
JMS_IBM_Encoding - 500
CamelJmsDestinationName - queue:///queueName?targetClient=0 (tried with target as 1 as well)
```

I'm trying to send the msg through java based apache camel framework and the msg type is in string
below is the detailed error msg,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: JMSWMQ2007: Failed to send a message to destination 'queueName'.; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSWMQ2007: Failed to send a message to destination 'queueName'.  JMS attempted to perform an MQPUT or MQPUT1; however IBM MQ reported an error.  Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2142' ('MQRC_HEADER_ERROR').
```

Comment: What version of MQ jar files are you using.

Comment: i'm using com.ibm.mq.allclient 9.1.3.0, jms 2.0.1

Comment: I am unclear why you would ever need to set the format to be MDE - just use the V2 MQMD fields as you need them, and a V2 MQMD will be used by the JMS classes to hold the field. In fact, I suspect a V2 MQMD is ALWAYS used by the JMS classes. Perhaps you can explain to us why you believe you need to set the format to this value and we will be able to help you further.

Comment: Since i'm sending the msg to mainframe, and in mainframe job designed in such a way that they couldn't read only the msg content first, setting the header to MQHMDE would wrap the header info in the msg content and the job can be processed, so setting the format MQHMDE is the requirement in order to process the data at mainframe

Comment: Can you show a code sample of what you are attempting?

Comment: Setting the format to MDE does not do what you describe you want. The use of the format MDE is only for the V2 MQMD fields. If an application uses an MQMD V2 and uses some of the fields in it, then a channel would convert those fields into an MDE in the message body and only an MQMD V1 would be used for the MQMD. Using an MDE does nothing with the MQMD V1 fields. You do not appear to be using an MQMD V2 fields anyway. So to reiterate, setting the format to MDE will NOT wrap the header info into the message.

Comment: Also, I notice you have set the character set to the Encoding value and the Encoding value to the character set. Suggest you swap those around and set your format to describe you data, e.g. string, and then show us what failure the getter is seeing and we can help you further.

Comment: Did you have any chance to try out the suggestion and show us the details of the failure that the getter is seeing?